# Parse.com Anywall tutorial order posts according to the distance to the active user

Tags: android, geolocation, sql-order-by, parse-platform

I am a begginer in parse, I have been following parse Anywall tutorial for android https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android

In the example code, there is a customized query, which order items according to the order in which they were created.

```
// Set up a customized query
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost> factory =
    new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost>() {
      public ParseQuery<AnywallPost> create() {
        Location myLoc = (currentLocation == null) ? lastLocation : currentLocation;
        ParseQuery<AnywallPost> query = AnywallPost.getQuery();
        query.include("user");
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.whereWithinKilometers("location", geoPointFromLocation(myLoc), radius
            * METERS_PER_FEET / METERS_PER_KILOMETER);
        query.setLimit(MAX_POST_SEARCH_RESULTS);
        return query;
      }
    };
```

In this partion of the code, I already have the location of the user (myLoc var), and each object retrieved bring its location (under "location" field). My question is, how can I use this fields to order posts according  to their distance to the active user?

Comment: you can use `myLoc.distanceTo(Location location)` to find the distance.

Comment: @hypd09, how can I embed distanceTo into the ParseQuery?

Comment: never worked with that but a quick search gives me `post.getLocation().distanceInKilometersTo(myPoint)`. So loop through them and do it on device or server side. I presume on device would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amswering myself :)

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#geo-query

> Now that you have a bunch of objects with spatial coordinates, it
>   would be nice to find out which objects are closest to a point. This
>   can be done by adding another restriction to ParseQuery using
>   whereNear.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PlaceObject");
query.whereNear("location", userLocation);
```

Answer (score 2):

Distance queries will default to sorting by nearest to farthest, unless you specify some other sort order using `orderByAscending()`/`orderByDescending()`.

Simply remove any orderBy statements from your query and you'll get the sorting you want.

Comment: in fact, I was just thinking about removing query.whereWithinKilometers(...), since I want all post to be visible.
If I add query.include("location") does the default to sorting by nearest to farthest still works?

Comment: @thalesfc no, you would have to re-sort client-side if you did that.